# When i'm using volley in android studio how to get response and iterate over Json ? if it is multi-dimensional array

Tags: json, android-studio, android-volley

I can't use JsonObjectRequest instead of StringRequest because I need send it via POST method

After analyzing lot of solutions I posted the question here

My php api output is looks like

```
[
  {
    "username": "arun",
    "password": "kumar"
  },
  {
    "username": "arun",
    "password": "ak"
  },
  {
    "username": "arun",
    "password": "mypass"
  },
  {
    "username": "arun",
    "password": "TestPW"
  }
]
```

In Android side I am using below code to fetch data from web, in the method
    public void onresponse()
I don't know how to get above json response, and also iterate over response to print all data in response

```
String url = "http://myipaddress/index.php";

StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new response.Listener<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
      JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);
      String output = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonobject.length(); i++) {
        // print all usernames and passwords
      }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

  }
}) {
  @Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    return params;
  }
};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: Your API response is an array so `new JSONObject(response);` should be throwing an exception. Isn't it?

Comment: @vader Yes, then I'm using String `output=response.toString();` It works, But I need to Iterate over `response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to iterate over the `JSONArray` and get every element as a `JSONObject` then get the `String` properties named `"username"` and `"password"` from each of them.

try this:

```
    String url = "http://myipaddress/index.php";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
          JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
          for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            final String username = object.getString("username");
            final String password = object.getString("password");
            // print the output
            Log.d("TAG", "username=" + username + ", password=" + password);
          }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

      }
    }) {
      @Override
      protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        return params;
      }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

Ideally you should use class models instead, and deserialize directly into this class.

```
public class UserLoginInfo {
  public String username;
  public String password;
}
```

This will make the object much more easy to use and give you the benefits of type safety and autocomplete.

[This is a link](https://medium.com/quick-code/parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley-83d6715776f8) from a short google search on how to do it with Google's `gson` library.

> IMO use [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Happy coding! :)